# Unlock sim after passing opportunity to unlock on iPhone startup

Tags: iphone, unlock, sim

This must be some basic stuff but I'm unable to figure it out.
I've restarted my iPhone, inserted my security code and then when the numpad appeared to insert my SIM pin code, I pressed the home button and now I can't trigger that numpad again to insert my pin code.

The only thing I see is `Locked SIM` in the upper left corner and can't do anything about it.

The question: How can I trigger the panel to unlock my SIM card again?

Comment: This is such an insane problem! Why doesn't Apple keep the lock screen around as one of the apps so you can come back to it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On iOS 10, go to Settings > Phone > SIM PIN to unlock your SIM.

On iOS 15.1 - > 16.4.1, go to Cellular, select the plan (you may have more than one), and SIM PIN should be the next-to-last option on the second group (after Carrier Services, before SIM Applications).

[image: Cellular > Plan settings iOS 15.1]

You can also disable the SIM PIN on that screen.

Comment: no longer an option...

Comment: not workin on 14.8

Comment: Please expand on how does this not work, or ask a new question referencing this one. The comment by itself it's not very helpful to diagnose or find out what is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Turning the Airplane mode on and off also shows the dialog again.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, thank you. On my phone, the SIM PIN option is neither in Settings > Phone, nor in Settings > Mobile Data and does not even turn up in Settings search.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with ESIM PIN.

Answer (score 6):

Note that on the iPad (the model with a SIM card option) the setting for unlocking the SIM is under Settings > Mobile Data > SIM PIN.

Comment: It’s the same in iPhone iOS 15.

Answer (score 2):

You can also place a call, the phone will show the unlock question again.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for SIM pin. Then just remove sim and reinsert it. Restart mobile. You will get message box to enter code.